# What is the 1000th positive integer whose digit sum is equal to 9?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

1 - 9

2 - 18

3 - 27

...

1000 - ?

Comment: sorry, i don't know how to ask this question properly

Comment: So, you are looking at the sequence of numbers who have digit sum equal to exactly nine and are wanting to know what the thousandth entry in the sequence is, yes?

Comment: yeah, but without using brute-force method

Comment: The sequence appears on oeis as [A052223](http://oeis.org/A052223).  You could read the comments and links on that page for more information.  The thousandth entry in your sequence is the number $117000$.

Comment: It is a question my friend randomly asked me, I don't know if this is a hard or easy problem to solve, I searched but nobody have asked this kind of question before.

Comment: Is there any way we can know the answer without listing every other entries in the sequence?

Comment: @Snoob These numbers should be multiples of $9$. But you need to skip some multiples because the sum of the digits of some multiples is not $9$ (but a multiple of it).

Comment: Isn't it $9 * 1000 = 9000$ and $9+0+0+0=9$ ?

Comment: @SteveLin you are not understanding the question apparently.  $9000$ would be the thousandth term in the sequence of multiples of nine with no other restrictions.  However, the sequence in question is specifically of those numbers which not only are multiples of nine, but are specifically those multiples of nine whose digit sum is exactly nine and not higher.  It begins: 9,18,27,...81,**90,108**,117,... Notice that it skipped 99 because the digit sum here is eighteen, not nine.  Similarly, it skips many others.  $9000$ is only the $220$'th term in this sequence.

Comment: @JMoravitz ah I just realized what it means! I'm sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can begin by estimating the number of digits the number we want has.

If we want a number with at most $k$ digits to have digit sum $9$, this is the same as writing $9$ as an ordered sum of $k$ nonnegative integers. By the stars and bars method ([Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))) there are $\binom{9+k-1}{k-1}$ ways to do so.

So there are $\binom{9+2-1}{2-1} = 10$ such numbers that are less than $100$, $\binom{9+3-1}{3-1} = 55$ such numbers less than $1000$, $\binom{9+4-1}{4-1} = 220$ such numbers less than $10000$, $\binom{9+5-1}{5-1} = 715$ such numbers less than $10^5$, and $\binom{9+6-1}{6-1}=2002$ such numbers less than $10^6$. So the $1000^{\text{th}}$ number in the sequence is between $10^5$ and $10^6$: it has $6$ digits.

Next, we can figure out what the first digit is. In addition to the $715$ numbers we've found with $5$ or fewer digits, the number of $6$-digit numbers whose first digit is $1$ in the sequence is $\binom{8+5-1}{5-1} = 495$, because its remaining $5$ digits sum to $8$, and $715+495 > 1000$. So the number we want is $1xxxxx$.

Similarly, we can figure out the second digit. In addition to the $715$ numbers we've found with $5$ or fewer digits, the number of $6$-digit numbers beginning $10\dots$ in the sequence is $\binom{8+4-1}{4-1} = 165$ (there are $4$ digits remaining, that add up to $8$). $715+165 = 880 < 1000$, so our number is past that. The number of $6$-digit numbers beginning $11\dots$ in the sequence is $\binom{7+4-1}{4-1} = 120$, and $120 + 880$ puts at $1000$ exactly.

This tells us that the number we want is the largest number of the form $11xxxx$ whose digits add up to $9$. We get the largest number by putting as large a digit as we can as early as we can, so the number we want is $117000$.